# Get all file names of opened Excel workbooks

Tags: excel, vb6

In Vba Excel we can use `For Each WBB In Workbooks` to get all opened Excel file names, so how about in vb6? I can use the following codeto get all opened Excel file names and add to vb6 combobox. How can I do the same in VB6?

```
For Each WBB In Workbooks
   combobox1.additem WBB.name
Next WBB
```

Comment: In exactly the same way, but with also putting your Excel instance variable in front of the `Workbooks`.

Comment: Can show me the correctly code for it ?